# Is it possible to rearm Microsoft Office 2007 similar to Vista/Win7?

Tags: windows, microsoft-office-2007, activation

Is it possible to rearm Microsoft Office 2007 trial before activation period in a similar way that can be done for Vista/Win7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible for Office 2007.

However, it will be possible with [Office 2010](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/09/04/how-to-rearm-and-extend-office-2010-activation-grace-period-for-free-180-days-usage/).

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer all of my searching on google kept returning info about it for 2010 and when I added -2010 to my googlefu almost no results other than keygen related sites so i figured it wasn't likely but figured it was worth asking.